# Hibernate HQL equivalent to Oracle parallel keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

Do you know any possibility to use the Oracle special keyword " /*+ parallel(n) */ " into a HQL Hibernate query?

You can see an example of this feature here: http://searchsystemschannel.techtarget.com/feature/Using-Parallel-SQL-to-improve-Oracle-database-performance

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there is no support for native SQL hints in HQL. [HHH-2736](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2736) which targets this issue is open since years.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the SQL is, you could use a stored outline to detect the query and add the hint at runtime. It can be tricky to get right, though - and can break if the query changes a little bit.

More info: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/outlines.php

Answer (score 1):

You won't need a hint if you set the degree of parallelism for the table:

```
alter table your_table parallel;
```

Although this will affect all queries that perform a full table scan on your table, which may or may not be beneficial.